# Why is json_extract_scalar returning null

Tags: sql, json, google-bigquery

I have a fairly simple string-formatted json column in a BigQuery database I am trying to flatten.

| id | relationships |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {'ownerObject': {'data': None}, 'investmentObject': {'data': {'type': 'assets', 'id': '40'}}, 'securityObject': {'data': None}, 'segmentObject': {'data': None}, 'dataItemObject': {'data': {'type': 'dataItems', 'id': '13161'}}, 'scenarioObject': {'data': {'type': 'scenarios', 'id': '13'}}} |

Running:

```
SELECT 
  id,
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(relationships, '$.investmentObject.data.type') as Invest_Type
FROM periodicData
```

Gives me:

| id | Invest_Type |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | *null* |

I would expect the column **Invest_Type** to be = *asset*. But no matter what I try on this json column, I always end up with *null*:

- `JSON_EXTRACT(relationships, '$.investmentObject.data.type') as Invest_Type` = *null*
- `JSON_EXTRACT(relationships, '$.dataItemObject.data.type') as Invest_Type` = *null*
- `JSON_EXTRACT(relationships, '$.dataItemObject') as Invest_Type` = *null*
- `JSON_EXTRACT(relationships, '$') as Invest_Type` = *null*
- `relationships as r` = *The full json* (as expected)

I have been doing similar operations over the past week on a lot of tables with no issue, but somehow this table is stubborn. What could I be doing wrong?

[image: How relationships looks in the schema]

How *relationships* looks in the schema

[image: How relationships looks in the preview]

How *relationships* looks in the preview

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query works, but your json is not correctly formatted.

Change single quote to double quote and add quotes around "None".

a crude version:

```
with cleaned as (select id, replace(replace(relationships, "\'","\""),"None","\"None\"") as relationships from inputtable)
SELECT 
  id,
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(relationships, '$.investmentObject.data.type') as Invest_Type
FROM cleaned;
```